# Error occurs while deploying ADF application to WebLogic 10.3 server

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic-10.x

We are having trouble deploying an ADF application being worked on by a colleague using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.9.0 to a standalone Weblogic 10.3 server so I was asked to post up a question here to see if anyone knows the cause of the problem.

```
Deployment Summary
Application Server
- Name: StandaloneWLServer
- Platform: Weblogic 10.3
- Overwrite modules: yes
- Deploy to selected instances in the domain: WC_CustomPortal (Running)
- Deploy as a standalone application

JDeveloper Deployment Log
[12:15:43 PM] ---- Deployment started. ----
[12:15:43 PM] Target platform is (Weblogic 10.3).
[12:15:43 PM] Retrieving existing application information
[12:15:43 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[12:15:43 PM] Building...
[12:15:52 PM] Deploying 3 profiles...
[12:15:52 PM] Wrote Archive Module to C:\Public\JDeveloper\mywork\CG22App11g\Model\deploy\CG22App11g_Model_adflibCG22App11g1.jar
[12:15:54 PM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\Public\JDeveloper\mywork\CG22App11g\ViewController\deploy\CG22App11g_ViewController_webapp1.war
[12:15:55 PM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to C:\Public\JDeveloper\mywork\CG22App11g\deploy\CG22App11g.ear
[12:15:55 PM] Deploying Application...
[12:16:09 PM] [Deployer:149191]Operation 'deploy' on application 'CG22App11g' is initializing on 'WC_CustomPortal'
[12:16:10 PM] [Deployer:149193]Operation 'deploy' on application 'CG22App11g' has failed on 'WC_CustomPortal'
[12:16:10 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application CG22App11g on WC_CustomPortal.: null.
[12:16:10 PM] Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException
[12:16:10 PM] See server logs or server console for more details.
[12:16:10 PM] weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException
[12:16:10 PM] #### Deployment incomplete. ####
[12:16:10 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)

Weblogic Server Log:
[2016-10-21T11:39:11.393-04:00] [WC_CustomPortal] [ERROR:7] [BEA-149265] [Deployer] [host: oscls-lims-ap21.osc.uscg.mil] [nwaddr: 10.149.177.197] [tid: [STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <WLS Kernel>] [ecid: 0000LVbtLUMB9DR_UXs1yc1O1uHz0000WH,0] [TARGET: /Farm_UCM_domain/UCM_domain/WC_CustomPortal] [TARGET_TYPE: weblogic_j2eeserver] Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1477064346998' for task '58'. Error is: 'java.lang.NullPointerException'[[
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.security.jps.internal.config.deploy.AbstractCredentialDeployment.cleanupTempFiles(AbstractCredentialDeployment.java:141)...
```

Related Information
I was able to deploy and run the same app in the Integrated WLS server in the JDeveloper (Studio Edition: 11.1.1.9).
I was able to compile and build an EAR file but failed to deploy the EAR via Oracle Enterprise Manager with the same error message.

Comment: I have the very same problem. Do you have any idea of what might be the problem? I have ADF installed in both the Standalone Server and the Integrated Server. Versions are: 11.1.1.66.73 for the Integrated, 11.1.1.64.93 for the standalone.

Comment: That particular problem was caused by different versions of ADF between what ADF version was being used by the integrated WLS in  JDeveloper and the version that was installed on the stand alone server. To correct the problem I had to compile the application and build the EAR using a previous version of JDeveloper (11.1.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Which exact version of WebLogic are you using? Did you install the ADF Runtime on that server?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/index-091111.html#Application_Servers